# Is there any way to click on "plain text" using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, click

Apologies if this question was answered before, I want to click on an area in a browser with plain text using Selenium Webdriver in python

The code I'm using is:

```
element_plainText = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class, "WgFkxc")]')
element_plainText.click()
```

However this is returning "ElementNotInteractableException". Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is *trying* to be helpful here, by telling you why it won't click on the element; `ElementNotInteractableException` means it thinks that what you're trying to click on isn't clickable.

This usually happens because either:

- The element isn't actually visible, or is disabled
- Another element is "overlapping" the element, possibly invisibly
- You're clicking something Selenium thinks won't do anything, *like plain text*

There's two things I'd try to get around this.  Firstly, Actions.  Selenium has an Action API you can use to cause specific UI events to occur.  I'd suggest finding the co-ordinates of the text, then making Selenium click those co-ordinates instead of telling it to click the element.  Read more about that API [here](https://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html).

Secondly, try clicking it with Javascript, using a Javascript Executor.  That can often give you the same outcome as using Selenium directly, without it being so "*helpful*".